# How to add multiple keyboard shortcuts to one command in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I add multiple keyboard shortcuts to a single command in VS Code?

As an example (from the comments), `ctrl` + `0` & `ctrl` + `1` should both do the same command/action. So completely separate shortcuts doing the same command.

Comment: Are you thinking like `ctrl`+`k`, `ctrl`+`c` to comment a block (as in multiple keys in series to do a thing), or are you thinking `ctrl`+`0` and `ctrl`+`1` should do the same thing?

Comment: That would be a macro

Comment: @zedfoxus `ctrl` + `0` & `ctrl` + `1` should do the same action/command.

Comment: @CharlieFish does the answer below get you what you wanted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say there are 2 bindings to close window like so:

[image]

Let's say we want to add one more keybinding like CMD+K, CMD+1. You could do that by right-clicking a command and choosing copy like so:

[image]

Then, click on an icon on the top right corner to open keyboard shortcuts JSON. The icon has an curved arrow on a page:

[image]

Your user-defined keybindings.JSON will show up. Type this in it:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "cmd+k cmd+1",
        "command": "workbench.action.closeWindow"
    }
]
```

Save and close.

Now you will see 3 keybindings for the action like so:

[image]

Now, try your new keybinding.

Comment: The faster way is to right click the command and select "Add Keybinding..."